# Why the program hangs after pressing the connect button?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, freeze

I want to start a server that will run regardless of whether there are clients or not, but when I press the connect button it(the GUI) hangs even if I started a new thread for function `runServer()`.
Thanks in advance, and help is appreciated.

```
 class HandleAClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;

    public HandleAClient(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ioex){
            System.err.println(ioex);
        }
    }

}
//==========================================================================  
//==========================================================================
private void runServer()
{
    try{


        while(true){ 
           Socket socket = server.accept();
            HandleAClient task = new HandleAClient(socket);
            new Thread(task).start();
        }  
    }catch(IOException ioex){
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }

}//end method runServer
  //=====================================================================
 //=====================================================================


   private void Connect_BtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    username = UserName_TF.getText();
    passwordtext = Password_TF.getText();

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, passwordtext);      
        if(conn.isValid(0))
            connected = true;

        jButton3.setEnabled(true);
        jLabel4.setText("Connected");
        UserName_TF.setEnabled(false);
        Password_TF.setEnabled(false);

        //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            runServer();
        //});

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.err.println(e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You started a new thread, but that new thread only creates streams (which dont seem to be used anywhere). `runServer()` isn't executed on that thread.

Comment: @Vince but doesn't the line  //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            runServer();
        //}); mean that i started a new thread for runServer()

Comment: Nope, that means you're submitting your `runServer()` code to the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which is the same thread that handles events such as user input & render requests. Since `runServer()` blocks until a connection is accepted, it's blocking the EDT from processing critical events like painting, resulting in the freezing you see.

Comment: @Vince if there is a quick way would you suggest how to fix that....?

Comment: *"if there is a quick way would you suggest how to fix that....?"* `SwingWorker` (it's quick for me to say, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to the following (**Thanks to Vince recommendations**)

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

//private int var;

public MyThread() {
    //this.var = var;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}

//=========================================================================
private void Connect_BtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    username = UserName_TF.getText();
    passwordtext = Password_TF.getText();

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, passwordtext);      
        if(conn.isValid(0))
            connected = true;

        jButton3.setEnabled(true);
        jLabel4.setText("Connected");
        UserName_TF.setEnabled(false);
        Password_TF.setEnabled(false);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established");

            new Login.MyThread().start();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.err.println(e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```